# magento .htaccess password protect inner pages (not homepage)

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I would like to use .htaccess to password protect all inner pages of Magento, except the home page. e.g. 
http://www.example.com/abc (password protect)
http://www.example.com (home page, no need to password protect)

I tried to use the `setifenv request_uri = "/" => allow`, but didn't work. It still password protect all pages including the homepage.
I also tried a few ways inside the Magento admin URL rewrite, but those won't work either.

Any expert can help? thx

E

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using apache:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/index.html$ norequire_auth=true
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/$ norequire_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=norequire_auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your root htaccess file and don't forget to change your admin url, `.htpasswd` file page.

```
<Files "admin">
        AuthName "Cron auth"
        AuthUserFile E:\wamp\www\magento\.htpasswd
        AuthType basic
        Require valid-user
    </Files>
```

Create .htpasswd file in your root folder and add below username and password (set default username:admin and password: admin123)

```
admin:$apr1$8.nTvE4f$UirPOK.PQqqfghwANLY47.
```

Please let me know if you still facing any issue.